Confusion regarding Z-transform of unit step sequence in MATLAB
I am using MATLAB and trying to find ztransform of heaviside(n) which is unit step sequence
I am studying book Signals and Systems Laboratory with MATLAB
Book by Alex Palamides and Anastasia Veloni
I have attached snap of book but when i try to run this code in MATLAB ,  i  am not getting same results as book

My MATLAB code
clc;clear;close all
syms z n
f=heaviside(n)
X=ztrans(f,z)




If you look up Matlab's Heaviside function, you'll see that it is not equal to the unit step sequence $u[n]$, because, unlike $u[n]$, it returns the value $1/2$ for $n=0$. Hence, it is given by
$$h[n]=u[n]-\frac12\delta[n]\tag{1}$$
and, consequently, its $\mathcal{Z}$-transform is
$$H(z)=\frac{z}{z-1}-\frac12=\frac{1}{z-1}+\frac12$$
as correctly claimed by ztrans.

Can you please explain, how you wrote H(z) = z/(z-1) -1/2 = 1/(z-1)+1/2

@DSP_CS: Have you tried to prove it yourself? Please give it a go, it's really absolutely basic.

Got it. Thanks alot
